# Comma seperator for the list of the map having String arguments

Tags: java, list, jsp, jstl

I have few values in the list of the map which are string.

```
List<Map<String, String>> myItem;
request.setAttribute("myItem", myItem);
```

These values either have numeric values or the string .
For example "123456" , "hello"

For the numeric value I want to add the thousand seperator on it and for string I want to ignore that.

I tried the below given code which gives the exception.

```
<c:forEach items="${myItem}" var="myItem" varStatus="loop">
                    <tr id="selectedFromComparable${loop.index}" data-column="0">
                        <td style="display: none;">index${loop.index}index</td>
                        <td class="teleblue addFilter" ><c:out
                                    value="${myItem.Group}"></c:out></td>




                                <fmt:formatNumber pattern="#,##0" 
                            value="${myItem['key']}" var="formattedVariable" />
                            <c:out value="${formattedVariable}"></c:out>
                            <td class="totValue">${formattedVariable}</td> 


                            <td class="totValue">${myItem["key"]}</td>
                        <td class="monthValue">${myItem["key_2"]}</td>
                    </tr>               
                </c:forEach>
```

Considering the values I have in the myItem["key"] as "123456","Hello","55555","32","Meaw".

Comment: Format it when you populate the map: not in the JSP. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html

Comment: Hi, Is there no way to handle it in the jsp itself ?